# AWS EBS Node app failing to restart automatically

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nodemon

We have a node application deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EBS) and when app crashes it is not getting restarted automatically.
We are using nodemon command to run the app. Below is the command in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
     "start": "nodemon --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=4096 --exec babel-node app.js"
  }
```

We also have a Procfile which have below content

```
web: npm start
```

After app crashes we can see below in eb-engine.log

```
web: #033[31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

But app is not restarting. We tried pm2 and forever instead of nodemon but didn't help.

Let me know what we are missing. I couldn't find proper documentation around this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What didn't work when you used pm2? It's restart strategies are pretty good. You can now use [Exponential Backoff Restart Delay](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/#exponential-backoff-restart-delay) to handle restarts after app crashes and ease the pressure on your database etc with `pm2 start app.js --exp-backoff-restart-delay=100`. For EC2 reboots you can also add a [Startup Script](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#generating-a-startup-script) with `pm2 startup` to start after server crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk supports Auto Scaling so you don't need to use nodemon or pm2, but simply start you app as a node application: `node app.js`.

Now if you want Auto Scaling to replace instances whose application has stopped responding, you can use a [configuration file to configure the Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html) to use Elastic Load Balancing health checks:

**Example .ebextensions/autoscaling.config**

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Properties:
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
```